# How to inject env var into withAWS in Jenkins using options

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to inject env vars into a `withAWS` in the options s

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'myimage'
        }
    }
    environment {
        ROLE = 'pipeline'
        ACCOUNT = '1111111111' 
    }

    stages {

        stage('Test aws') {
            options {
                withAWS(region: 'us-east-1', role: 'pipeline' , roleAccount: '1111111111')
            }
            steps {
                sh 'env | grep AWS'
            }
        }

        stage('Build TypeScript') {
            options {
                withAWS(region: 'us-east-1', role: env.ROLE, roleAccount: "${env.ACCOUNT}")
            }
            steps {
                sh 'env | grep AWS'
                sh 'env | grep ROLE'
                sh 'env | grep ACCOUNT'
                sh 'npm run create-db-schemas'
                sh 'npm run build'
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Here is what my logs show:

```
[Pipeline] { (Test aws)
[Pipeline] withAWS
Setting AWS region us-east-1 
 Requesting assume role
Assuming role ARN is arn:aws:iam::1111111111:role/pipelineAssumed role arn:aws:sts::1111111111:assumed-role/pipeline/Jenkins-PoC-credit-app-
 [Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ grep AWS
+ env
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=**********
AWS_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=**********
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=**********
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withAWS
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Build TypeScript)
Retrieving credentials from node.
[Pipeline] withAWS
Setting AWS region us-east-1 
 [Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ grep AWS
+ env
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_REGION=us-east-1
[Pipeline] sh
+ grep ROLE
+ env
ROLE=pipeline
[Pipeline] sh
+ env
+ grep ACCOUNT
ACCOUNT=523572232308
[Pipeline] sh
+ npm run create-db-schemas

{"level":"ERROR","message":"Problem getting secret with name domain_gateway_rds_root: Secrets Manager can't find the specified secret.","metadata":{},"timestamp":"2024-01-11T02:41:12.300Z"}
/tmp/jenkins-85bb3fbc/workspace/C_credit-app_foo/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-secrets-manager/dist-cjs/protocols/Aws_json1_1.js:1240
    const exception = new models_0_1.ResourceNotFoundException({
                      ^


ResourceNotFoundException: Secrets Manager can't find the specified secret.
```

Analysis:

1. In the first stage I hard code the account and role, and it gets AWS credentials just fine, as show from an env dump; which also shows my `ROLE` and `ACCOUNT` vars are valid too
2. In the second stage, I try to do the same, and I get failure because the secrets I need are not available, because it didn't log in (though the `withAWS` seems to know the region to use).

What is the correct way (if it's env possible) to inject env vars into the options? I have done this exact thing in the past and it's not working.

Comment: Do you need the variables to be environment variables? This seems like a much better use case for pipeline parameters.

Comment: Yes, because the values need to be injected in a classic pipeline. This is for deployment